# Not able to push or pop navigation in Swift4 Xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift4, xcode9.2

```
let homepageViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomepageViewController") as! HomepageViewController
self.navigationController?.popViewController( animated: true)
```

I have added this code to my UINavigationBar left button
.What should i do to use push and pop in my app 
I try to use same in the UIButton also but same error is coming
please help me for this.

Comment: show your full error code

Comment: Probably you dont have any navigationcontroller.

Comment: that wouldnt cause exception - he is optionally unwrapping it

Comment: hi, NSExceptions log to console. we need that ;)

Comment: sorry there is no error msg for this code, its was some other error and nothing is showing after tapping on the button where we give that action

Comment: did you embed navigation controller in storyboard or code?